# Determining a sum formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

> Determine the sum formula for
>
> $$\frac 1{1\cdot 5}+\frac 1{5\cdot 9}+\frac 1{9\cdot 13}+\cdots +\frac1{(4n-3)\cdot (4n+1)}$$  and prove it by induction.

Let us analyse the four first elements of the series:

$$\frac1{1\cdot5}, \frac1{5\cdot9}, \frac1{9\cdot13}, \frac1{13\cdot17}$$

Clearly we see a pattern between every subsequent fraction, and the identity between the second element of the denominator and the first element of the second fraction's denominator. Hence the very first term, with $n=1$ is

$$\frac{1}{n(n+4)}$$
The second term  with $n=5$
$$\frac{1}{n(n+4)}$$

and so on.

But how do I arrange these terms into a sum?
Thanks

Comment: @AnneBauval it a similar question, but the answer seems to be related not to the sum, but to the n-th term?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz It is the very same question. $a_n$ in that post denotes the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is $\frac{n}{4n+1}$. Use $\frac{1}{(4n-3)(4n+1)}=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n+1})$.